# How to use Any() instead of foreach?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I need to run a stored procedure on SQL Server, using LINQ, and throw an exception if it returns any rows. The following code works, although the `foreach` loop does not communicate my intent well enough:

```
foreach (var badData in context.BadDataForDay(today))
{
    throw new Exception("Bad data found");
}
```

I wanted to write something like `IF EXISTS()` in SQL, but with LINQ:

```
var badData = from p in context.BadDataForDay(today) select p;
if (badData.Any())
{
    throw new Exception("Bad data found");
}
```

This code compiles but `Any()` blows up with the following message:

> Specified cast is not valid

What am I missing? Is `Any()` the right method to use in this case?

**Edit:**
I debugged, and the code blows up before the stored procedure is called, at the following generated line:

```
        return ((ISingleResult<BadDataResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
```

To get it to work, I did the following:

I added another stored procedure and dragged it to my context:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.BadDataExists
    @AsOfDate DATETIME
AS 
    BEGIN ;
        SET NOCOUNT ON ;
        SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Cnt
        FROM    SomeTable
        WHERE   SOME conditions ;
    END ;
```

I used this code:

```
         foreach (var badDataCount in
           context.BadDataExists(asOfDate).Where(badDataCount => badDataCount.Cnt > 0))
             {
```

Although it works now, I would really like to understand what I was missing.

Comment: Can you give the full exception message?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `BadDataForDay` method.  Incidentally - when you can get it to work you should simply be able to do `if(context.BadDataForDay(today).Any())`

Comment: is bad data really an exception? Do you expect the data to sometimes be bad?

Comment: I assume your foreach code would also blow up, if `context.BadDataForDay(today)` would return any data...

Comment: @Andras: I have a stored procedure BadDataForDay, and the method with this name was generated in my context when I dragged that procedure into my pad.

Comment: @Mitch: the procedure is developed to return bad data. At this time I do not have constraints or triggers to enforce that it is always clean.

Comment: @Dan: the complete message is this: "Specified cast is not valid"

Comment: @Daniel: you right, foreach stopped working as well.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: you were correct. When you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Arne: done. I added some explanation, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `foreach` code would also blow up, if `context.BadDataForDay(today)` would return any data...

The code that translates the objects from the database into C# objects and returns them as an enumerable inside `BadDataForDay` seems to be performing a cast that compiles fine but that blows up at runtime, because the object that should be casted has the wrong type.

The reason why `Any` and `foreach` only blow up when data is returned is simple: Without data, no cast will be performed.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var badData = context.BadDataForDay(today);
if (badData != null && badData.Any())
{
    throw new Exception("Bad data found");
}
```

What exception is throwing?

Comment: the complete message is this: "Specified cast is not valid"

Answer (score 1):

Any is used with a condition like this for example (I am not sure this is what you need):

```
  var res = (from c in context.Cusotmer 
    where c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.year == 2010)
    select c);
```

in your case might be:

```
var badData = (from p in context.BadDataForDay 
where p => p.Days.Any(d => d == today) select p);
```